# Omitting a moderator

Tags: interaction, bias

I'm wondering what the effect is if I don't include moderators in my model? Is this the same or different from an omitted variable bias? I am having a hard time grasping this conceptually.

More information: I did a GEE analysis for a binary outcome for a publication. The independent variables were the study group and several demographic variables along with a few other participant characteristics. The CI of the odds ratios were quite wide, but I think it is due to the small sample size. One reviewer indicated we should include moderators in the model to decrease the variability of the estimates. I have never heard of this, so I was wondering if this was correct.

Comment: Can you make this more concrete?  It'd help to see more about the actual scenario, or a simplified or contrived one if that's too complex/sensitive to publicize.

Comment: do you mean to omit the moderator from the model and keep only the interaction terms ?

Comment: I edited the original question to give background information.

Answer (score 3):

For causal modeling, I think the popular idea is to adjust for *precision* variables (see Vittinghoff et al "Regression Methods in Biostatistics"). Precision variables are variables that are independent of the exposure of interest but highly prognostic of an outcome. Technically, the actual point estimate shouldn't change much, but the confidence intervals should "narrow" substantially. This is only feasible if you've collected very comprehensive data on the sample and you are able to justify why the variable's role in the multivariate analysis should serve that intended purpose. For this reason, Stephen Senn has advocated using *adjustment for prognostic variables* in analyses of randomized controlled clinical trial data to *improve power and reduce NNT* (a very important point!).

Suppose for instance I were looking at the relationship between mammographic breast density and breast cancer risk. Density is a physiologic aspect. Genetic risk factors, such as the presence or absence of the BRCA gene in extreme examples, or family history of breast cancer as a proxy for elevated genetic risk, would serve as a precision variable in such an analysis.

It's very important to ensure that prognostic variables or precision variables are *not in the causal pathway* (e.g. a direct consequence of the exposure of interest, or a "mediator"). This will eliminate your power to detect an association between the outcome and exposure of interest. Returning to the breast density example, adjusting for prior benign findings or recalled mammographic screens would serve this purpose. Dense breasts are more likely to confuse radiologists and cause them to recall patients for additional screening or even a biopsy. This is one of the ways by which dense breasts are indeed actually associated with greater breast cancer risk, however adjusting for this downstream effect will cause you to infer otherwise.

As a side note, for most categorical analyses (esp logistic regression), the idea that point estimates "do not change" must be relaxed somewhat. This is due to issues of non-collapsibility of the odds ratio. So, while the odds ratio and confidence interval may be compared between models which do and do not adjust for prognostic factors, you may expect small changes in the odds ratio due to this. Contrast that with confounding. I personally never compare adjusted and unadjusted results because I expect point estimates to be substantially different after adjustment for confounding variables, and it's only the latter (confounding adjusted) that I would believe.

Comment: am I correct that the precision variables you refer to are *not* the same as moderators? Not knowing much (but wanting to learn more), my impression is that moderators are variables that *are* related to the exposure of interest.

Comment: I don't think the precision variables are the same as moderators. A moderator is supposed to influence the strength or direction of the association between the dependent and independent variable. So, it is an interaction effect basically. I'm just wondering if omitting a moderator is different from omitting a dependent variable.

Comment: @RussLenth OP's question seems to be the source of the confusion. By referring to the width of the CI as the main problem, they seem to indicate that they are seeking precision variables. It suggests that perhaps they are interested in adjusting for precision (or prognostic) variables.

Comment: AdamO- My question also stemmed from my confusion as to what the reviewer is even talking about. I thought perhaps I was misunderstanding something. I'm also unsure why it matters that the confidence intervals are wide. This is social science research. It doesn't seem to me to be the most important thing to know if women are 3 or 5 times more likely than men to react in a certain way, just that they are significantly more likely.

Comment: @SB3 I would have to have read both the reviewer comments as well as your paper to understand the subtle nuances to the question. I have reviewed a number of studies where the effect size and directions were consistent with hypothesized values, but the tests "failed to achieve significance" (that is an irksome sentence for me). If you said something similar, as in "our study was underpowered" (meaning that the 95% CI actually overlapped a null value), then it makes sense for the reviewer to question whether you have sufficiently utilized adjustment in this study.

Comment: @SB3 on the other hand, such explorations quickly turn into perilous fishing expeditions that greatly inflate type I error rates for inference (due to a large number of models being considered and no controlling for multiple comparisons). It is actually very similar to a phenomenon called Munchaesen's Grid where subgroups defined by adjusted predictors are given undue weight and influence. Perhaps, just maybe, you have a null finding and that is what's most important.